# primeng rowStyleClass does not work as expected

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I have a primeng datatable (1.1.0) in my angular 2 application and I am using rowStyleClass to set a class to a row which is expanded.

The problem is, it works fine, when the row is expended, but if I collapse it, so it is still with the expanded class.

**component**

```
  rowStyle(rowData: any, rowIndex: number): string {
    if ((this as DataTable).isRowExpanded(rowData)) {
      return 'ui-state-highlight';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
```

**view**

```
<p-dataTable tableStyleClass="table" *ngIf="model.result.length > 0" [rows]="itemsPerPage" [paginator]="isPaginatorVisible()"
      (onSort)="resetPagination()" [value]="xModel.ergebnis" [(selection)]="selected" expandableRows="true" [rowStyleClass]="rowStyle">
...
```

row if expanded:

```
<tr class="ui-datatable-even ui-datatable-odd ui-state-highlight ui-widget-content" ng-reflect-klass="ui-widget-content ui-state-highlight" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
```

then collapsed:

```
<tr class="ui-datatable-even ui-datatable-odd ui-widget-content ui-state-highlight" ng-reflect-klass="ui-widget-content" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
```

As you can see, ui-state-highlight is only removed from ng-reflect-klass, but not from the class itself. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: It seems like you are doing it right, and that this functionality is broken. The collapseRow options also do not provide a solution. This ticket proposes a hacky CSS workaround: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1845 `p-datatable tbody > tr:not(.ui-widget-content)`

Comment: Try to manually detect changes and update view, after change - with Angular's ChnageDetector:

      `if (!this.changeDetectorRef['destroyed']) {
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually detect changes and update view, after change - with Angular's ChnageDetector:

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  rowStyle(rowData: any, rowIndex: number): string {
    if ((this as DataTable).isRowExpanded(rowData)) {
      return 'ui-state-highlight';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
    if (!this.changeDetectorRef['destroyed']) {
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
  }
```